# Jasmine Data Provider - how to run single test

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I want to implement Jasmine Data Provider for my Protractor tests that read data from excel sheet.

This will run the same test multiple times for each data row.

How do I run a single test from the data rows?

Comment: sorry, but could you tell why you chose `excel`?

Comment: @Oleksii - I am using .xlsx file to read application data. Application is huge and each row in .xlsx file is a test case that fills out different questions in application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try js-xlsx parser.

Here is an example how to parse an excel file to json:
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/demos/typescript/lib/index.ts

Then you can just pass it to jasmine data provider framework and iterate it:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider